# Magento 2 : Delivery Calendar in before-shipping-method-form

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-address

We are adding a delivery calendar using `before-shipping-method-form` using knockout.

We need to get delivery address postcode, so that we can pass this in a json request to get relevant information from our delivery system? I have tried `quote.shippingaddress` but this doesn't work with a guest checkout.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to achieve this so that it updates if the customer changes the postcode.